# Proving $\frac{\cos\frac12nx\,\sin\frac12(n+1)x}{\sin\frac12x}-1=\frac{\cos\frac12(n+1)x\,\sin\frac12nx}{\sin\frac12x}$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove the following?
$$\frac{\cos\left(\frac12nx\right)\;\sin\left(\frac12(n+1)x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12x\right)}-1 = \frac{\cos\left(\frac12(n+1)x\right)\sin\left(\frac12nx\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12x\right)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use common denominator, then expand anything with $+$ sign in a trigonometric function:
$$\cos\left(\frac12nx\right)\;\sin\left(\frac12(n+1)x\right)-\sin\left(\frac12x\right)=\cos\left(\frac12(n+1)x\right)\sin\left(\frac12nx\right)$$
Let's use $a=\frac12 nx$ and $b=\frac12x$. Then the above expression is
$$\cos a\sin(a+b)-\sin b=\cos(a+b)\sin a$$
Expanding the sine and cosines of sum, you get:
$$\cos a(\sin a\cos b+\cos a \sin b)-\sin b=(\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b)\sin a$$
I hope you can take it from here (just move everything top one side).